# What to use for Messaging with C#

Tags: c#, messaging

So my company stores alot of data in a foxpro database and trying to get around the performance hit of touching it directly I was thinking of messaging anything that can be done asynchronously for a snappier user experience.  I started looking at [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) but don't know how well C# will hook with it.  Wanting to hear what all of you guys think.

edit : It is going to be a web application.  Anything touching this foxpro is kinda slow (probably because the person who set it up 10 years ago messed it all to hell, some of the table files are incredibly large).  We replicate the foxpro to sql nightly and most of our data reads are ok being a day old so we are focusing on the writes. plus the write affects a critical part of the user experience (purchasing), we store it in sql and then just message to have it put into foxpro when it can.  I wish we could just get rid of the foxpro, unfortunately the company doesn't want to get rid of a very old piece of software they bought that depends on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ActiveMQ works well with C# using the Spring.NET integrations and NMS. A post with some links to get you started in that direction [is here](http://thefreakparade.com/2008/04/15/two-message-exchange-patterns-using-activemq-and-nms-via-springnet/). Also consider using MSMQ (The System.Messaging namespace) or a .NET based asynchronous messaging solution, with [some options here](http://thefreakparade.com/2008/06/03/esbs-for-the-microsoft-net-platform/).

Comment: This blog is no more available

Answer (score 4):

MSMQ (Microsoft Message Queueing) may be a great choice. It is part of the OS and present as an optional component (can be installed via Add/Remove Programs / Windows Components), meaning it's free (as long you already paid for Windows, of course). MSMQ provides Win32/COM and [System.Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging) APIs. More modern Windows Communication Foundation (aka Indigo) [queued channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/queuing-in-wcf) also use MSMQ. 
Note that MSMQ is not supported on Home SKUs of Windows (XP Home and Vista Home)

Answer (score 1):

Its worth mentioning that the [ActiveMQ open source project](http://activemq.apache.org/) defines a [C# API for messaging called NMS](http://activemq.apache.org/nms/) which allows you to develop against a single C# / .Net API that can then use various messaging back ends such as

- [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)
- MSMQ
- TibCo's EMS
- any STOMP provider
- any JMS provider via [StompConnect](http://stomp.codehaus.org/StompConnect)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at MSMQ. It can be used by .NET and VFP, but you'll need to rewrite to use them. Here's an article that tells you how to use MSMQ from VFP. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/foxpro/ms917361(v=msdn.10)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this isn't what you are asking for...
Have you considered some sort of cache behind the scenes that acts a bit like the "bucket system" when using asynchronous sockets in c/c++ using winsock?  Basicly, it works by accepting requests, and sends an immediate response back to the web app, and when it finally gets around to finding your record, it updates it on the app via AJAX or any other technology of your choice.  Since I'm not a C# programmer I can't provide any specific example.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Does the Fox app use .CDX indexes? If so, you might be able to improve performance by adding indexes without needing to change any program code. If it uses .IDX indexes, though, the change would have to be done in the actual app.

Answer (score 0):

As the problem is with writes, I would look more towards >removing< any unneeded indexes on the tables. As is common in RDBMS, every index on a FoxPro table slows down a write operation as the indexes need to be updated, and as you aren't reading directly from (or presumably directly querying) the table you shouldn't need very many indexes. You might also want to look at any triggers or field rules on the tables as they may be slowing down the write operation. Be sure your referential integrity is still preserved, though..